# Measure time in milliseconds for C code on windows

Tags: c

I want to measure the time of a function written in c running on windows in milliseconds. I know that clock() does not work and gettimeofday is not supported. any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean that clock() doesn't work?  Do you mean that the resolution is not high enough?

Answer (score 3):

On Win32 you can use GetPerformanceCounter.

I've used it to implement both hi-res timing and GUIDs on Windows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx

Combined with GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() you should have all you need.

Comment: "Can you provide me the code" - Wait, your name is "Programmer"! :) Surely it will be a good learning experience for you.

Comment: What does minimum time resolution mean?

Comment: Meaning if you called the time function twice in a row, how granular would the time value show. Just because a time value may be in milliseconds doesn't mean that calling it twice in 2 milliseconds will return a timevalue of 2 different milliseconds. Functions with low granularity will return the same value multiple times, depending on how fast you call them. Thats why you need higher resolution.

Answer (score 0):

See [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408).

Comment: GetTickCount does report time in milliseconds, but it may not have millisecond resolution.  Depending on the age of the machine and the version of windows, you may notice that the smallest measurable increment with GetTickCount is between 10 and 20 milliseconds.  GetPerformanceCounter will give you better resolution if your PC has a high resolution timer (most do).

Comment: Exactly. GetTickCount() called multiple times may return the same value, if I recall, at least on older Windows (pre-2000). At the time (1999?), on Win98 and PocketPC(ver?) I had to write a better GUID and it had to work in batch mode. With GetTickCount() I would generate many of the same, so my retry loop had to retry a few times. Not good for performance. GetPerformanceCounter() was the solution.